# Telerik report html text box not reading breaklines correctly

Tags: asp.net, telerik-reporting

I have been trying to use linebreaks in the HTML Textbox in telerik reports (using Q1 2015 sp1 Telerik version) but `<br>` is not being rendered as a linebreak. As you can see in the first picture below, I've tried \r\n, \n, replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` in both textbox and HTML Textbox but in the second picture the html tags are not being rendered like HTML tags.

What am I missing to make this work?

Designer code:
[image: TestReport Designer code]

rendered:
[image: TestReport rendered]

Comment: have you tried <br />?

Comment: <br /> should work. But if your version don't have that, you may find solution here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/need-help-getting-new-line-in-textbox

Comment: I tried <br />. I wasn't putting it in the correct place. There's a Design Editor and HTML Editor and I was putting it all in the Design editor.

Comment: So now is it working? After putting in HTML editor mode

Comment: Yes! In design mode it was replacing the brackets with &lt; and &rt; when I looked at it in html mode. But it works now in HTML mode.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/html-text-box-not-reading-breaklines-correctly#9Ro8WtoXMUy9vODaojnNoA